# Using HTML5 EME (Encrypted Media Extensions) for JS

Tags: javascript, html5

I am thinking about developing a paid JS script, and I wanted to prevent its piracy by using HTML5's EME to safely decrypt and use my JavaScript file client-side.

Can EME be used for more than just audio/video content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### No.

You cannot currently use Encrypted Media Extensions (EME) to prevent JavaScript piracy.

Because JavaScript is interpreted client-side by the user's browser, the source code can be retrieved.

#### What are Encrypted Media Extensions (EME)?

According to [Google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/eme):

> Encrypted Media Extensions provides an API that enables web applications to interact with content protection systems, to allow playback of encrypted audio and video.

The [W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/encrypted-media/) for Encrypted Media Extensions explains:

> This proposal extends `HTMLMediaElement` providing APIs to control playback of encrypted content.

#### What is a HTMLMediaElement?

Mozilla [describes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement) the `HTMLMediaElement` as:

> The `HTMLMediaElement` interface adds to `HTMLElement` the properties and methods needed to support basic media-related capabilities that are common to audio and video. The `HTMLVideoElement` and `HTMLAudioElement` elements both inherit this interface.

In other words, `HTMLMediaElement` simply refers to `<video>` and `<audio>` content.

From this information, we can conclude that Encrypted Media Extensions act as a gateway between a client's web browser and DRM software: **specifically audio and video**. <sub>[[Source]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypted_Media_Extensions)</sub>